# Как получить доступ к Service из другого класса в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть данный класс:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AgeInputState extends AbstractState {

    private final ClientService clientService;

    public AgeInputState(boolean isInputIndeed) {
        super(isInputIndeed, State.AGE_INPUT);
    }
```

В котором идет сохранение в бд с помщью сервиса.
Также пакет класса указал в Application в аннотации @ComponentScan.
Но идея выдает ошибки `Class doesn't contain matching constructor for autowiring` при наведении на имя класса и также ошибку `Variable 'clientService' might not have been initialized` при наведении на ClientService.

Как это исправить, чтобы можно было подтянуть слой сервиса?

Comment: репозитории есть? И если можно структура папок и классов

Comment: Использовать аннотацию `@Autowired`?

Comment: ваша проблема не в переменной clientService, а в том, что ваш класс AgeInputState  является компонетом с единственным констуктором, который принимает boolean isInputIndeed. как вы думаете, каким образом спринг должен узнать значение этой переменой при создании экземпляра данного класса?

Comment: и замените RequiredArgsConstructor на AllArgsConstructor

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали аннотацию @RequiredArgsConstructor , но при таком случае Spring не заинжектит ваш сервис.
Совет поменять эту аннотацию на @AllArgsConstructor тоже не поможет - у вас уже есть свой конструктор.

Правила внедрения зависимостей в спринге:
- Если есть только один конструктор, лежат бины ---> он их заинжектик
- Если конструкторов несколько или 0, спринг не будет ничего инжектить
- Если вы создали свой конструктор, и он не единственный - укажите @Autowired перед нужным конструктором
- Если не хотите париться с конструктором, перед каждым Бином укажите @Autowired

В вашем случае:
1.) Удалите аннотацию @RequiredArgsConstructor

2.) Измени

`private final ClientService clientService;`

на

```
@Autowired 
private final ClientService clientService;
```